# Holiday in Canada- Tourist Visa with Austrian Citizenship

Tags: visas, canada, eta

I'm currently planning on spending my holidays in Canada (about two weeks). I'm from Austria, and according to the official website, Austria is on the list of the Visa-exempt countries. 
Therefore, I won't need a Visa, and I only have to apply for an eTA, because I'll fly to Canada.
Is that right?

I'm always very cautious when it comes to Visa applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that’s correct, you need an eTA http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?country=AT&result=2

Comment: ...and your passport, and nothing else.